# Connect points to plane/Draw Polygon

Tags: c, algorithm, math, 3d, polygon

I'm currently working on a project where I want to draw different mathematical objects onto a 3D cube. It works as it should for Points and Lines given as a vector equation. Now I have a plane given as a parametric equation. This plane can be somewhere in the 3D space and may be visible on the screen, which is this 3D cube. The cube acts as an AABB.

First thing I needed to know was whether the plane intersects with the cube. To do this I made lines who are identical to the edges of this cube and then doing 12 line/plane intersections, calculating whether the line is hit inside the line segment(edge) which is part of the AABB. Doing this I will get a set of Points defining the visible part of the plane in the cube which I have to draw.

I now have up to 6 points A, B, C, D, E and F defining the polygon ABCDEF I would like to draw. To do this I want to split the polygon into triangles for example: ABC, ACD, ADE, AED. I would draw this triangles like described [here](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/TriangleRasterization/TriangleRasterization.html#algo3). The problem I am currently facing is, that I (believe I) need to order the points to get correct triangles and then a correctly drawn polygon. I found out about convex hulls and found [QuickHull](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~ungor/courses/fall06/papers/QuickHull.pdf) which works in three dimensional space. There is just one problem with this algorithm: At the beginning I need to create a three dimensional simplex to have a starting point for the algorithm. But as all my points are in the same plane they simply form a two dimensional plane. Thus I think this algorithm won't work.

My question is now: How do I order these 3D points resulting in a polygon that should be a 2D convex hull of these points? And if this is a limitation: I need to do this in C.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to express the coordinates of the intersection points in the space of the plane, which is 2D, instead of the global 3D space. Depending on how exactly you computed these points, you may already have these (say (U, V)) coordinates. If not, compute two orthonormal vectors that belong to the plane and take the dot products with the (X, Y, Z) intersections. Then you can find the convex hull in 2D.

The 8 corners of the cube can be on either side of the plane, and have a + or - sign when the coordinates are plugged in the implicit equation of the plane (actually the W coordinate of the vertices). This forms a maximum of 2^8=256 configurations (of which not all are possible).

For efficiency, you can solve all these configurations once for all, and for every case list the intersections that form the polygon in the correct order. Then for a given case, compute the 8 sign bits, pack them in a byte and lookup the table of polygons.

---

**Update**: direct face construction.

Alternatively, you can proceed by tracking the intersection points from edge to edge.

Start from an edge of the cube known to traverse the plane. This edge belongs to two faces. Choose one arbitrarily. Then the plane cuts this face in a triangle and a pentagon, or two quadrilaterals. Go to the other the intersection with an edge of the face. Take the other face bordered by this new edge. This face is cut in a triangle and a pentagon...

Continuing this process, you will traverse a set of faces and corresponding segments that define the section polygon.

[image]

In the figure, you start from the intersection on edge HD, belonging to face DCGH. Then move to the edge GC, also in face CGFB. From there, move to edge FG, also in face EFGH. Move to edge EH, also in face ADHE. And you are back on edge HD.

Complete discussion must take into account the case of the plane through one or more vertices of the cube. (But you can cheat by slightly translating the plane, constructing the intersection polygon and removing the tiny edges that may have been artificially created this way.)

Comment: Do the vectors relating to the plane need to be orthonormal? Because I have orthogonal not unit vectors, which also result in two (U,V) coordinates. The only difference are the actual values but not the relation between the coordinates of two points, isn't it?

Comment: No they don't, convexity is preserved anyway.

Comment: So this idea somehow was very obvious, but I didn't noticed it... Anyway now tried your first approach and it looks great! Relating to the second: I don't quite understand it^^ Should I precompute the order in which the verticies will be when I have this and that combination?

Comment: For every combination of the signs, there is a single corresponding (cyclic) ordering of the edge intersections. For example, for 1 negative and 7 positive, the section is always a triangle, and if you know which among the 8 corners is negative, that you know what is the triangle.

Comment: Alright, so I actually understood it correctly. Thanks for that interesting idea, I may try to implement it if I have some spare time